# Warning: a promise was created in a handler at but was not returned from it

Tags: node.js

```
 Promise.map(response.orders.orders, function(order) {

                  if(order.order_destination == "OC"){
                        return searchOrdersBll.promisifyOrdersOC(order).then(function(order){
                          return searchOrdersBll.orderCommentHistory(order);
                          })
                    }else if(order.order_destination == "OB"){
                        return searchOrdersBll.promisifyOrdersOB(order).then(function(order){
                           return searchOrdersBll.orderCommentHistory(order);                               
                          })
                    }                       

                })
                .then(function(data) {
                    args.order = data;
                    args.track_orders = [];
                    htmlResponse(req, res, partials.orderedtemplate, args);
                })
```

getting issues:

> Warning: a promise was created in a handler at
>   var/www/html/customerservice/server/apps/search/controller/search_bll.js:56:29
>   but was not returned from it,
>       at Function.Promise.map (/var/www/html/customerservice/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/map.js:164:12)

Comment: If your `htmlResponse` function is promise generator, you should return it's result in container function. Now your async calls chain brakes on that line with returning `undefined` result to up-level caller.

Answer (score 1):

You just need to return the promise returned by `htmlResponse`:

```
Promise.map(response.orders.orders, function(order) {

                  if(order.order_destination == "OC"){
                        return searchOrdersBll.promisifyOrdersOC(order).then(function(order){
                          return searchOrdersBll.orderCommentHistory(order);
                          })
                    }else if(order.order_destination == "OB"){
                        return searchOrdersBll.promisifyOrdersOB(order).then(function(order){
                           return searchOrdersBll.orderCommentHistory(order);                               
                          })
                    }                       

                })
                .then(function(data) {
                    args.order = data;
                    args.track_orders = [];
                    return htmlResponse(req, res, partials.orderedtemplate, args);
                })
```